# "WOULD HAVE" OR "MUST HAVE" FOR A SPECULATION IN THE PAST

Tags: grammar

The context is as below:

A: Yesterday I visited Jim's home at 4 pm. But He wasn't at home.

B: He **would have been** out to the gym. I know that he often goes to the gym at that time.

I now that I can use:

(1)I think he **was** out to the gym....

(2)He **must have been** out to the gym...

(3)He **would have been** out to the gym...

(4)He **could have been** out to the gym...

What is the difference between these sentences above?

The most thing I want to know is if it is correct to use (3)"would have been" to make a speculation.

Comment: (2) and (3) mean that you are fairly confident that he was **at** the gym - (1) and (4) that you think he was possibly there.

Comment: @KateBunting any difference between (2) and (3)?

Comment: Well, _must have_ sounds more confident than _would have_ to me.

Comment: Among could have, must have, could have, will have, would have, might have. I can use all of them, right? And "would have" expresses the least certainty. Right?

Comment: Wrong. If you read my comment again, you will see that I said that _I think he was_ and _he could have been_ express _less_ certainty. _Might have_ and _may have_ also express less certainty.

Comment: “Will have” can’t be used? Right?

Comment: "He will have been at the gym" can be used if you know that Jim is normally there at that time.

Comment: @KateBunting If so, "would have" and "will have" have nearly the same meaning. Right?

Comment: **In this context**, yes (not normally).

Answer (score 3):

"*He would have been at the gym*" suggests that is what you would *expect*. For example, if it was someone's usual habit to be at the gym at a certain time you would reasonably expect them to be there.

"*He must have been at the gym*" demonstrates a different kind of surety. It suggests that you have reached the conclusion, perhaps by considering some evidence or eliminating other possibilities, that he must have been there.

Neither mean 100% certainty.

By contrast, "*he could have been at the gym*" only suggests a *possibility*. This speculation could be given alongside others, for example "*he could have been at the gym, or at his home*".

Comment: “He would have been at the gym” can be used to show my opinion based on what I know about his habit, not a inference. Right? And this have the same meaning as “ I think he was at the gym” Right?

Comment: @LEHANH Yes and no. Yes, "he would have been at the gym" is pretty much as you describe. But "I think he was at the gym" suggests you have more specific information than just an awareness of their routine. That would suggest more that you had specific knowledge and are recalling it as best you can. For example, if I said "I think that's correct" it means you are recalling a memory but are not completely sure about it.

Answer (score 1):

The structure "must have" indicates *a conclusion arrived at by a process of deduction*. In other words, Sentence (2) means something like, "*The only place he could reasonably have been was at the gym*".

The structure "would have" indicates *a conclusion arrived at through by reference to other information*, like in this case, knowing his schedule. So in this case, Sentence (3) means something like, "*He goes to the gym every Saturday afternoon, so that's almost certainly where he was.*"